# Laptop doesn't start if charger is not plugged in

Tags: laptop, battery, power

I got an old Lenovo z50-70. It was mostly used with a charger as previous owner says.

The issue is: it doesnt start if the charger is not plugged in. Whenever I try to start it without charger, it makes a split-second noise (sounds like the fan is trying to start and next moment there is no power) then nothing happens.
However, if I plug the charger in and press the power button, it makes the same noise, but this time does it 2 times and on second time starts and after that everything is fine.

Normally I'd say the battery is dead, but the weird thing that if it is started, it can work without charger for a good amount of time.
What could be the issue? I cant afford buying a new battery rn just to find out that it wasn't the issue.

Couldn't find anything similar to my case on the internet, I hope someone here can help me

Comment: My guess is that the BIOS tests the battery and finds it's too weak to start the computer. Or that the battery is to weak to accomplish whatever it is trying to do at startup, such as giving the fan a good push.

Answer (score 1):

> I got an old Lenovo z50-70. It was mostly used with a charger as
> previous owner says

If a battery is left at 100% on a charger, it will eventually die. It is doubtful the owner would have known about Battery Threshold charging, indeed the old machine may not even support that.

So at this point, based on your own description, the battery is dead and needs to be replaced.  If the battery were good, it would charge, you would know that and it would start on the battery, but it does not.

So until you can purchase a new battery, you will continue to need to leave it plugged in.

Comment: The main reason I am not sure it's battery issue is the fact that it starts with those two weird sounds I described in my post. It tries to start 2 times (always successful on second) even if I remove the battery and start with only charger plugged in

Comment: I am not sure about the sounds - related to your laptop. But needing the charger to start the computer means the battery is on its last legs. It may have been discharged by the prior owner and then just left off with no charging at all.

Comment: By the way, I have seen many batteries expire at customers. Not uncommon. And what you describe in your post is a prime cause.